# Netbeans - installing SASS

Tags: ruby, netbeans, sass

I have had a few attempts at installing SASS on netbeans.  I have followed the following tutorial:

http://kgagliardo.com/blog/netbeans-sass-windows-7

I get the below error  when creating and trying to save the SASS file and no CSS file is created.

> ""C:\Ruby193\bin\sass.bat" "--cache-location"
>   "C:\Users\Leanne\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.4\sass-compiler"
>   "C:\Users\Leanne\Documents\work\freelance\sites\fws_templates\gamer\scss\store.scss"
>   "C:\Users\Leanne\Documents\work\freelance\sites\fws_templates\gamer\css\store.css"
>   '"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. Done."

I've been stuck on this all morning, please help...

***UPDATE*** 
I've tried to follow the instructions provided below and it still does not work, although I did get a slightly different error message:

> "C:\Ruby193\bin\sass.bat" "--cache-location"
>   "C:\Users\Leanne\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.4\sass-compiler"
>   "C:\Users\Leanne\Documents\work\freelance\sites\fws_templates\gamer\scss\store.scss"
>   "C:\Users\Leanne\Documents\work\freelance\sites\fws_templates\gamer\css\store.css"
>   Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable:
>   foundation/components/accordion.
>                 Load path: C:/Users/Leanne/Documents/work/freelance/sites/fws_templates
>   (DEPRECATED)
>           on line 10 of C:\Users\Leanne\Documents\work\freelance\sites\fws_templates\gamer\scss\foundation\foundation.scss
>           from line 11 of C:\Users\Leanne\Documents\work\freelance\sites\fws_templates\gamer\scss\store.scss
>   Use --trace for backtrace. Done.

However Now I simply get the original error message again.  No idea what to do. See image below showing that I have done everything according to the instructions (I think).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eekyt.png

[image]

Comment: your Path to ruby is `C:\Ruby193\bin` go back and edit your path environment variable to point to `C:\Ruby193\bin` . At the moment you have `C:\Ruby\192\bin` :-)

Comment: Well spotted.  I have changed it to 193 but still have the same error.

Comment: And Now remove the backslash between Ruby and 193 . Your Path is set to : `C:\Ruby\193\bin` :-) ! your `.bat` is in Folder : `C:\Ruby193\bin`

Comment: Oh yeah, I feel like such an idiot! Thanks for pointing that out.  Now I have the 2nd error message showing again.  I assume the 2nd error message is nothing to do with the original and so you should perhaps answer this question with the above so you can get he +50 ;)

Comment: Thanks ! Also `LukasMac` 
has tried to lead you in the right direction. However, he has brought the error to the wrong path into play. `c:\Ruby\192\bin`

Comment: Here's a [walkthrough to **setup SASS in Netbeans**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34714409/383904)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your path environment variable points to the wrong folder**

Your Path to ruby is C:\Ruby193\bin

Go back and edit your path environment variable to point to C:\Ruby193\bin . At the moment you have C:\Ruby\192\bin

**EDIT**

And Now remove the backslash between Ruby and 193.
Your Path is set to : C:\Ruby\193\bin :-) !
your .bat is in Folder : C:\Ruby193\bin

**TIP**

Go to Options

Miscellaneous --> CSS Preprocessors

check : Generate extra information (debug)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have path to `ruby.exe` which is `c:\Ruby\192\bin` in you `PATH` variable.

In Windows 7:

1. Right click on My computer and select `Properties` -> Go to
   `Advanced` Tab -> Click on the `Environmental Variables` button
2. In the Environmental Variables window highlight `PATH` variable in
   System variables section and click `Edit`
3. Append `;c:\Ruby\192\bin` to the end (the semicolon is intentional)
4. Restart `command prompt`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  For point 3 I now have, "C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Ruby\192\bin" for the PATH system variable.  Is that correct?  Also I'm not sure what to do for point 4.

Comment: Im getting a new error message.  Not sure if this is totally unrelated or not...Ive amended the original query above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have path to ruby.exe

As simple, reinstall ruby, use ruby [installer for windows](http://www.rubyinstaller.org/).

When you go through the installation wizard, you’ll come to this options screen:

From what I can tell, the only option that you need to check on that one is the middle option, which helps your command-line instructions recognize where to find (as it says) “Ruby executables”. Otherwise, you’ll get the error message “ruby is not recognized as an internal or external command” when you try to install Sass in the command prompt.
Go to Options

Miscellaneous --> CSS Preprocessors

check : Generate extra information (debug)

For more information go to [Setting Up Sass on Windows](http://www.impressivewebs.com/sass-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

They are all right in the above message. The problem is that Netbeans is not designed to pick up these changes instantaneously. Once you make the changes above, you have to RESTART Netbeans, so that the changes will be applied. This worked for me. Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you vote down? It did work for me. Please explain by adding a comment so that I know my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @Matheus No problem. Im glad this helped you. Please upvote my answer. Thank you.