# Installing sass in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: netbeans, sass

I know there are questions like this on SO, but none of the given solutions helped me.

I also tried to ask this question on netbeans forum, but they haven't responded to my questions, probably because they just don't know answers.

SO community is a "bit" bigger than the one on the netbeans forum, so I hope I'll get some clue.

I'm trying to get SASS working in Netbeans 8.0.2 (Ubuntu). I installed sass, it sits in /sur/local/bin/sass. I set up this path in NB options. I set up paths in project properties. And... nothing happens when I save a css file. Shouldn't there be at least a warning message if something's wrong?

Yes, I have "generate extra information (debug)" and "open output on error" checked. The path to the sass executable is also correct.

And yes, I also have "compile Sass files on Save" checked.

In project properties / Input and Output fields I tried relative and full urls. I also tried using ${web.root} variable.

I use Netbeans for PHP, but I don't think it matters.

None of these solutions work for me, especially that most of them is for Windows OS:

[How to use SASS with Netbeans 8.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965982/how-to-use-sass-with-netbeans-8-0-1)

[Cannot get SASS to output .css file in Netbeans 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169253/cannot-get-sass-to-output-css-file-in-netbeans-8-0)

[Netbeans - installing SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660942/netbeans-installing-sass)

Please help, I've been trying to make it working for the last 4 hours :(

Please tell me at least where can I find an error log or something.

**Update:** 
The log says:

> INFO [CPOnSaveHook]: processSavedFile called for Sass type on project
>   /var/www/html/analytics. INFO
>   [net.sickill.off.netbeans.NetbeansProject]: fileChanged: ignoring
>   internal file changes INFO
>   [org.netbeans.modules.css.prep.process.BaseProcessor]: Not compiling,
>   file /var/www/html/analytics/src/AppBundle/Resources/scss/admin.scss
>   not matched within current mappings
>   [Pair[/var/www/html/analytics/src/AppBundle/Resources/scss,/var/www/html/analytics/web/css]]

But as I said: In project properties / Input and Output fields I tried relative and full urls. I also tried using ${web.root} variable.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem.

In the project properties ->  css properties -> input/output fields there must not be / (a slash) at the beginning. So it should be e.g. "src/AppBundle/Resources/scss" instead of "/src/AppBundle/Resources/scss" And it should not be a full url (like /var/html/www/project...)

Also, using ${web.root} did not work.

Answer (score -1):

I solved may problem. In project properties -> css prepocessor -> uncheck compile sass files on save:

[image]